# Can't create BluetoothSocketServer with listenUsingInsecureRfcommOn on channel 1

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, sdp, rfcomm

So I have a raspberry pi that needs to send data to an Android device via Bluetooth. I have no control over the raspberry pi's code whatsoever (it was developed by someone else and is already running and can't be changed) and it sends data to the android device via rfcomm on channel 1. 
The Android device is the server while the raspberry pi is the client.

Here's the snippet where the problem arises.

```
BluetoothServerSocket bss;
BluetoothAdapter ba = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

Method m = null;
m = ba.getClass().getMethod("listenUsingInsecureRfcommOn", new Class[]{int.class});
bss = (BluetoothServerSocket) m.invoke(ba, 1);
bss.accept();
```

it gives me this error:

> W/System.err: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   
> W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   
> W/System.err:     at com.example.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:58)
> W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
> W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error: -1
> W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommOn(BluetoothAdapter.java:2458)
> W/System.err:  ... 3 more

I also did a sdptool browse for the device and it didn't show any service that was using rfcomm channel 1. The BluetoothServerSocket is created successfully when I select any other channel number.

Would love to hear from anyone who has experienced the same situation. Thanks.